# AEM 6.1 classic UI dialog to touch UI dialog customization in JS for Multifield

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, aem

I am working on converting classic UI dialog to touch UI dialog in AEM 6.1. 
I have a multifield dialog which is working fine in classic UI, I want to customize the js to convert it to touch UI. But

1. The multifield is not storing the values from the JS. Instead, it is displaying empty values.
2. Also, the Article Heading field in the dialog is a required field and dialog shouldn't be exit if it is empty, but the required functionality is not working with the touch UI.

I tried the following JS but couldn't understand what the problem is.

```
(function ($, $document) {
    "use strict";

    var _ = window._, Class = window.Class;

    ACS.TouchUI.MultiCompositeMultiField = new Class({
        toString: 'AARP Composite Multifield Store as Multi Value Field',
        extend: ACS.TouchUI.Widget,
        MULTI_VALUE_STORE: "MULTI_STORE",
        isMulti: false,

        getMultiFieldNames: function(){
            var cmf = this, mNames = {}, mName, $multifield, $template,
                $multiTemplates = $(".js-coral-Multifield-input-template");

            $multiTemplates.each(function (i, template) {
                $template = $(template);
                $multifield = $($template.html());
                if(!cmf.isMultiValueStore($multifield.data(cmf.ACS_COMMONS_NESTED))){
                    return;
                }
                this.isMulti = true;
                mName = $multifield.data("name").substring(2);
                mNames[mName] = $template.closest(".coral-Multifield");

            });

            return mNames;
        },

        buildMultiField: function(data, $multifield, mName){
            var cmf = this;

            if(_.isEmpty(mName) || _.isEmpty(data)){
                return;
            }

            _.each(data, function(value, key){
                if(key === "jcr:primaryType"){
                    return;
                }
                var currentElements = $multifield.find("li.coral-Multifield-input").length;

                if( Object.prototype.toString.call( value ) === '[object Array]' ) {
                    var numberOfElements = value.length;
                    if (numberOfElements > currentElements) {
                        var newNum = numberOfElements - currentElements;
                        currentElements = numberOfElements;
                        for (var i=0; i< newNum; i++) {
                            $multifield.find(".js-coral-Multifield-add").click();
                        }
                    }
                    var elementParts = {
                    key: key,
                    container: mName
                    };
                    _.each(value, function(fValue, index) {
                        var $field = $multifield.find("[name='./"+mName+"/" + this.key + "']").eq(index);

                        if(_.isEmpty($field)){
                            return;
                        }
                        cmf.setWidgetValue($field, fValue);
                    }, elementParts);
                } else {
                    if (currentElements === 0) {
                        $multifield.find(".js-coral-Multifield-add").click();
                    }
                    var $field = $multifield.find("[name='./"+mName+"/" + key + "']");

                    if(_.isEmpty($field)){
                        return;
                    }
                    cmf.setWidgetValue($field, value);
                }


            }, mName);
        },

        addDataInFields: function () {
            var cmf = this, mNames = cmf.getMultiFieldNames(),
                $form = $("form.cq-dialog"),
                actionUrl = $form.attr("action") + ".infinity.json";

            $.ajax(actionUrl).done(postProcess);

            function postProcess(data){
                _.each(mNames, function($multifield, mName){
                    cmf.buildMultiField(data[mName], $multifield, mName);
                });

                $document.trigger("touchui-composite-multifield-nodestore-ready", mNames);
            }
        },

        getMultiValueStoreMultifields: function(){
            return $("[" + this.DATA_ACS_COMMONS_NESTED + "='" + this.MULTI_VALUE_STORE + "']");
        },

        isMultiValueStore: function(name){
            return (name === this.MULTI_VALUE_STORE);
        },

        collectDataFromFields: function(){
            if (!this.isMulti) {
                return;
            }

            var $multifields = this.getMultiValueStoreMultifields();

            if(_.isEmpty($multifields)){
                return;
            }

            var $form = $("form.cq-dialog"), $fields,
                cmf = this;

            $multifields.each(function(counter, multifield){
                $fields = $(multifield).children().children(cmf.CFFW);

                $fields.each(function (j, field) {
                    fillValue($form, $(multifield).data("name"), $(field).find("[name]"), (counter + 1));
                });
            });

            function fillValue($form, fieldSetName, $field, counter){
                var name = $field.attr("name"), value;

                if (!name) {
                    return;
                }

                //strip ./
                if (name.indexOf("./") === 0) {
                    name = name.substring(2);
                }

                value = $field.val();

                if (cmf.isCheckbox($field)) {
                    value = $field.prop("checked") ? $field.val() : "";
                }

                //remove the field, so that individual values are not POSTed
                $field.remove();
                $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', fieldSetName +"/" + name+"["+counter+"]")
                    .attr('value', value)
                    .appendTo($form);
            }
        }
    });

    $document.ready(function () {
        var compositeMultiField = new ACS.TouchUI.MultiCompositeMultiField();

        $document.on("dialog-ready", function(){
            compositeMultiField.addDataInFields();
        });

        $document.on("click", ".cq-dialog-submit", function(){
            compositeMultiField.collectDataFromFields();
        });
    });
}(jQuery, jQuery(document)));
```

Comment: Can anyone please help. It is urgent....

Comment: Any errors in browser's developer console ?